# SQL Server: Making Monday the start of week

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue (and as reading, it's not just me) with SQL server settings for Sunday as first day of week. But my company needs the weeks to cover the period Monday-Sunday. I tried SET DATEFIRST 1, but it doesn't affect the results. A simple example: today is Sunday; when I enter the following code in SQL, it results in week 33, but it should show week 32, and week 33 should start from tomorrow:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
Select DatePart(week, getdate());
```

I changed the language in my login settings to British English, bit it didn't work, as well. Is there some other way to change the settings? 
In most of my queries I need to show the results for last week, with a similar where clause:

```
WHERE Week = (Select DatePart(week, getdate())-1)
```

If I can't globally change the settings, than how is it possible to transform the upper clause in such a way, so that to show the results from Monday to Sunday? I am an SQL beginner, searched for an answer in the internet, but couldn't adapt my code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, ...)` after setting `SET DATEFIRST 1`?

Comment: Yes, now it's working! I only replaced WEEK with  ISO_WEEK, as you advised, and it results in week 32, even without the SET DATEFIRST 1 addition. Maybe it's because I changed language to British English. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, ...)` after setting `SET DATEFIRST 1`. This should observe ISO week numbering, as documented in [DATEPART documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql).